# Center a DropDownList in a div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to center a DropDownList in a div please?

Here is my code :

```
<div id="divRech" class="icon-select-group form-control"> 
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHotelIslands" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" name="search-hotel-island"> 
  </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `select` tag isn't on `display: block` by default, you can place it in the middle of your parent div like that:

```css
div#divRech { width: 80%; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black; }
div#divRech #ddlHotelIslands { display: block; margin: auto; }
```

```html
<div id="divRech" class="icon-select-group form-control"> 
  <select ID="ddlHotelIslands" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" name="search-hotel-island"> 
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **Method 1** Please change your `select` to `display:block` and to make it center you can use `margin: 0 auto`
2. **Method 2** Please use transform property `transform:translate(-50%,-50%)` to make it into vertical and horizontal center

```css
.icon-select-group{
border:1px solid grey;
padding:20px;
position:relative
}
select{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-select-group form-control"> 
  <select> 
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```